# Loading a .wav into memory then playing it in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

None of the other answers I could find seem to work for me. I have put the contents of the `sound.wav` into a variable like so in order to embed the sound data into the executable **without dealing with resource files**:

`sound.h`:

```
std::string sound = R"(RIFFÆø^ WAVEfmt ...)";
```

Due to this sound file is about 30 seconds long, it is an extremely large variable consisting of *12,624 lines* of garbage (which could be the source of the problem).

I included `sound.h` in `main.cpp` then attempted to play the sound using the windows `playsoundapi`:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    PlaySoundA(sound.c_str(), nullptr, SND_MEMORY | SND_SYNC);

    return 0;
}
```

The program simply compiles, prints "Hello", and exits with code 0 without any errors. It feels like I've tried everything at this point so any info helps.

Comment: If the same code works when you load from a file containing the bytes that represents the same data, then you do have a problem with the definition of `sound`.

Comment: How did you do the raw binary data to text conversion? Remember that not all binary bytes can be represented as characters.

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a resource file which will handle the embedding for you

Comment: You don't check for errors when calling PlaySound

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::string` constructor you are invoking constructs a `std::string` object from the source sequence up to the first NUL character.

WAVE files use the [Resource Interchange File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format). After the `RIFF` chunk identifier, there's a 4-byte sequence designating the length. For files smaller than ~16.4MiB, the fourth byte is zero, so you wind up with a `std::string` of length 7. Even for larger files there will eventually be bytes with a value of 0, causing the `std::string` to store a truncated version of the input.

You have a number of options to deal with this (from least recommended to most recommended):

- Use a [`std::string` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes an explicit `count` argument. This avoids truncation of the input as would normally happen.
- Use an array, e.g. `unsigned char const sound[] = R"(RIFF ...)";`. Since C++ doesn't provide a way to describe binary literals it is recommended to initialize each element with a numeric value, e.g. `unsigned char const sound[] = { 0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46, ... };`.
- Link the audio file into the executable image's resources. This is the recommended way to place binary assets into an executable image. [Playing WAVE Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/playing-wave-resources) has sample code for retrieving the data.

Note that [`PlaySound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd743680(v=vs.85)) has a return value, that your code ignores. It's entirely likely for the call to return `FALSE` the way you are calling it. Observing errors should be your first order of action when diagnosing issues.